# Unable to create an Import/Export Job on the new Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying to set up an import job as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/); the problem is that we do not have "Classic" storage, rather we are trying to set it up with "New" storage. Using the new portal I cannot find the place where one is meant to create a new job. The linked article shows how to do this for classic storage on the old portal only.

I have tried using the second approach they mention, which is to use the API, but that is turning out to be more of a pain than I though.

Does anyone know where I can add an import/export job in the new portal? Is this possible with "new" storage? If I manage to get the API way to work, can it be applied to "new" storage or is it only for "classic"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Import/Export is not available in the Preview Portal, and does not work at this time with v2 storage accounts. Can you use a Classic storage account instead?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just to confirm, with v2 storage, import/export is not possible even through the API? Or did you mean that it is not possible through the preview portal?

Comment: I asked the storage team and they said it's not possible with v2 assets, period. But if Aung Oo (below) can help you with something that's may not public yet, I would definitely follow up with him.

Answer (score 0):

We may be able to provide a sample code to unblock your scenario. Can you please send an email with your detailed requirements to waimportexport@microsoft.com so that we can set up a call to discuss further.

Thanks,
Aung